# Python: How do I set the password on an ubuntu user account using Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to create a user account on a remote Ubuntu system using Fabric. I want the account to have a strong password. I can use the following to create the account:

```
 sudo('useradd -m test -s /bin/bash')
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to set the password. The useradd -p options requires an encrypted password. How do I set the password? How does the salt get passed to the remote system?

Example code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `chpasswd`. Unlike `passwd`, you can pass the username and password in the command's standard input. So you can for example upload a file containing the password and put this line in your fabfile:

```
sudo('chpasswd < my_password_file')
```

From `man chpasswd`:

The chpasswd command reads a list of user name and password pairs from standard input and uses this information to update a group of existing
   users. Each line is of the format:

user_name:password

The supplied passwords must be in clear-text.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
sudo('useradd %s' % username)
sudo('echo %s | passwd %s --stdin' % (username, username))
sudo('chage -d 0 %s' % username)
```

The password will match the username and the user will be prompted to change their password at first login.